# fatal error: libxml/xmlmemory.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

Can anyone explain to me that error and what should I do to solve it !?:

```
In file included from /home/jros/catkin_ws/src/kinectueye/include/MIXEDVISION/CModelStereoXml.h:6:0,
                 from /home/jros/catkin_ws/src/kinectueye/src/kinect_ueye.cpp:10:
/home/jros/catkin_ws/src/kinectueye/include/MIXEDVISION/CXml.h:6:31: fatal error: libxml/xmlmemory.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

CModelStereoXml, CXml and xmlmemory all are files in a library (so I can't edit it) that I use in my program kinect_ueye.cpp.

Comment: Most likely you need to set your include path to include the directory where `libxml` is.

Comment: I have others lib in the same diretory and all work fine only this one?

Comment: Might it be that you need to do `sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt-dev`? (Assuming ubuntu as distro.)

Comment: @Tobias I did but it doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It says `CXml.h` line 6 is:

```
#include <libxml/xmlmemory.h>
```

But `libxml/xmlmemory.h` is not in your include path. The include path is set with `-I` options on the compiler command line.

The error is "fatal" because compilation cannot continue past that point.

Find out where that file is actually installed and make sure the path to its `libxml` directory is in a `-I` option. For example, if it's installed in `/opt/local/include/libxml/xmlmemory.h`, then you need `-I /opt/local/include` on your command line.

> CModelStereoXml, CXml and xmlmemory all are files in a library (so I can't edit it)

Only the compiled code is in a library (`.a`, `.la`, or `.so` file) that you can't edit. The headers will be located somewhere else.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I'm looking for. just for more information :how can I do that without changing the compiler command line ?

Comment: I have no idea what kind of build system you're using. If you're using makefiles, then you can put a line like `INCLUDES += -I /opt/local/include` into your top-level `Makefile`. If you're using an IDE such as Eclipse, there should be a field in a dialog box for "include paths" that you put it in.